# Is JAVA2D the only rendering mode to display transparent PGraphics objects in Processing?

Tags: java, png, processing, java-2d, pgraphics

Is `JAVA2D` the only rendering mode in Processing in which `PGraphics` objects can be displayed with a transparent background (as opposed to `P2D` and `P3D`)? I have tried rewriting my code in the other two modes (`P3D`, `P2D`) but the backgrounds of the `PGraphics` turn out opaque (black by default)---perhaps I'm missing a method that would turn them transparent? The `png`s I'm displaying in the `PGraphics` objects are turning out transparent as expected; it's the backgrounds of the `PGraphics` that are opaque. I am working on a project and have currently selected `JAVA2D` in order to keep my `PGraphics` transparent, but wonder if I can alternately use `P3D` and its features instead.

From looking around online believe `JAVA2D` was the only mode that could render PGraphics transparent in earlier versions of Processing (1.*), and I'm wondering if this has changed with version 2?

Thanks in advance for your clarification and help!

**UPDATE:**

Below is a sample of my code (written in Eclipse in Java with Processing as a component). v.k.'s reply works great (with my `png`s) in the Processing pde, but I've been unsuccessful getting it to work in my project in Eclipse. Thoughts? :

Main class:

```
package tester;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import processing.core.*;

public class GraphicsMain extends PApplet{
int screenWidth = 800;
int screenHeight = 500;
PGraphicsMaker pgm = new PGraphicsMaker(this);
ArrayList<PGraphics> motifArray = new ArrayList<PGraphics>();


public void setup() {
    size(screenWidth,screenHeight,P3D);
    background(0);

    motifArray = pgm.makeMotifArray();

    if (motifArray.get(0) == null) {
        System.out.println("The motif array is unfilled!");
    }
}

public void draw() {
    for (int i = 0; i < motifArray.size(); i ++) {
        image(motifArray.get(i),200+(10*i),100);

    }


}

static public void main(String[] passedArgs) {
    String[] appletArgs = new String[] { "GraphicsMain" };
    if (passedArgs != null) {
        PApplet.main(concat(appletArgs, passedArgs));
    } else {
        PApplet.main(appletArgs);
    }
}
```

Second class:

```
package tester;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import processing.core.*;

public class PGraphicsMaker {
String filepath = "/a/filepath/here/";
PApplet parent;
int populationSampleSize = 16;
int stageWidth = 100;
int stageHeight = 400;
ArrayList<PGraphics> motifArray;
PImage pic;
PImage pic2;

public PGraphicsMaker(PApplet pa) {
    parent = pa;
    pic = parent.loadImage(filepath + "small_jones6.png");
    pic2 = parent.loadImage(filepath + "small_dresser10.png");
}


public ArrayList makeMotifArray() {
    String filepathTempPngs = "/a/filepath/here/tempPngs/";
    ArrayList<PGraphics> motifArray = new ArrayList<PGraphics>();


    for (int i = 0; i < populationSampleSize; i++) {
               motifArray.add(parent.createGraphics(stageWidth,stageHeight,parent.P3D));
        motifArray.get(i).beginDraw();
        motifArray.get(i).background(255, 255, 255, 0);
        motifArray.get(i).image(pic,10,10,100,90);
        motifArray.get(i).image(pic2,10,50,50,50);
        motifArray.get(i).endDraw();
        motifArray.get(i).save(filepathTempPngs + "motif" + i + ".png");
    }
    return motifArray;
}
}
```

**NOTE:**
I'm not certain that last `save()` function is necessary in `makeMotifArray()` in the second class (just another attempt to preserve transparency).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below worked for me in 1.5.1 and 2.0b8... If I got you right it is doing what you need... Check it out:

```
PGraphics p;

void setup(){
  size(400,400,P3D);
  p = createGraphics(400,400,P3D);
  smooth();
  stroke(180,90,210);

}

void draw(){
  background(180,90,210);
  p.beginDraw();
  p.background(220, 180, 40,0);
  p.noFill();
  p.stroke(220, 180, 40);
  p.translate(width/2 - (width/2 - mouseX), height/2, 400-mouseY*5);
  p.sphere(100);
  p.endDraw();
  pushMatrix();
  translate(width/2, height/2, -200);
  rotateY(radians(frameCount));
  rotateX(radians(frameCount/2));
  box(100);
  popMatrix();
  image(p,0,0);
}
```

Comment: hi @v.k. - I tried your code in the Processing pde and even substituted in my `png`s and it works great! Strangely, however, when I try the code in Eclipse (where I'm writing my project - using Processing as a component) it doesn't work. I've made an update my question above with the code from Eclipse. Thoughts?

Comment: UPDATE: I discovered that in Eclipse I was using a version of the Processing core.jar library from 2010 that came with a version of Proclipsing that I no longer use, but the library of which I use as an external reference. My copy of the Processing pde was using a much newer version of the core, and so your code worked there, but not in Eclipse. I've updated my core and and OpenGL libraries referenced in Eclipse and now everything's working great. Thanks!

Comment: Hey,happy to know it helped. Cheers.